# Where does C++ puts local variables?

Tags: c++

I would like to say that C++ puts local variables on stack.
But let's have a look at this code:

```
  class MyClass
  {
     private:
         std::map<std::string, std::pair<int, std::string> > data;

     public:
         void push(std::string a, int b, std::string c)
         {
            std::pair<int, std::string> temp;
            temp.first=45;
            temp.second=c;
            data[a] = temp;
         }
  };
```

At the end of push method call, temp variable should be deleted if this variable is on local stack. But my program works, and i do not know why. Do you think that data[a] = temp makes a copy of temp ? What should i do if i want to store pointers instead of making a copy ?

Comment: *"Do you think that data[a] = temp makes a copy of temp ?"* - yes of course, what else would it be doing ?

Comment: 1. It makes. See `std::string::operator =`. 2. To store pointers you should store pointers, i.e. use `std::map<std::string *, ...>` for example.

Comment: Raw pointers and containers? Sounds like a recipe for trouble... How would you manage object ownership and lifecycle? These questions are not trivial (see smart pointers such as `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`)

Comment: Why would you want to store pointers? If you want to make it more complicated then necessary go ahead but then you need to allocate the objects on the heap and make sure they get deleted (eg use smartpointers). The only reason would be if the objects are already stored somewhere which seems not to be the case here.

Answer (score 4):

`data[a] = temp;` certainly **does** take a value copy of `temp`: the *assignment operator* for `std::pair<int, std::string>` is used for that.

In C++11 there are ways of putting stuff on a `std::map` that obviate this deep copy. Refer to *move semantics* and *emplacement*.

Comment: Okay thanks. What should i do if a want to store addresses of original strings (a and c) ?

Comment: @Bob5421: Facetiously: think again about doing that. Don't store the original addresses.

Answer (score 3):

Of course `data[a] = temp;` makes a copy of `temp` and stores it in `data[a]`.
Since this is just a copy there is no problem.

If you store the address of `temp` inside `data` (changing its definition), then it will be a problem since it will store a dangling pointer.